# Create a gateway in CANoe

Tags: gateway, can-bus, canoe

I have two CAN networks: One via Virtual CAN connected over Wifi to my PC and one CAN network connected with VN1610 via USB to my PC.
How do I setup a „gateway“ in CANoe, so I can transfer CAN messages from one CAN network to another and the other way around. Do you have any suggestions or tipps?

i tried this solution:
https://support.vector.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0011376&sys_kb_id=97e44ea41b2614148e9a535c2e4bcbe6&spa=1

But I don’t get where to store this file and how to bind this file into my system in CANoe.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly your problem is? The file - as described in the link you have posted - is supposed to be added to a node in CANoe's simulation setup. This node has to be attached to both buses you want to bridge.

Comment: Hi, I tried to add a new node in both network, and tried the script I posted. But somehow I get the error: „4 : Message with ID F 155 could not be sent. Driver error.“  And the error: „Node ECU 3 (CAPL): [ECU 3] Output to bus system CAN channel 4 not allowed!“ That happens for both Node ECU 2 and Node ECU 3. To clarify my setup:  ECU 1 & 3 are in the first CAN network and ECU 2&4 are in the second CAN network. I applied the gateway that ECU 1 forward to ECU 3, ECU 2 forward to ECU 4 and the other way around.

Comment: Just for clarification. You have to add exactly ONE node and connect that node to two networks. Do this by: adding a node to one bus, then right-click, select "Configuration...", tab "Buses" and there make sure that the two busses are in "assigned busses". It would be very helpful if you could post pictures of your simulation setup. In your question you mention two CAN channels, thus I am a bit confused that "channel 4" occurs in your error message.